# hadoop : datanode not running?

Tags: java, hadoop

I configured and deployed hadoop for single node setup via [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)  tutorial. Everything deployed fine, but when I do jps for have a look on active processes, datanode is not shown. I manually tried to start datanode by going to $HADOOP_HOME/bin : hadoop -datanode, but to no avail. Basically to sum up, datanode process is not running at all for the hadoop cluster. Also, I want to know whether a single machine can have 2 hadoop installations. I am using one for mapreduce processes and another one for search engine. So their directory being different, is that okay ? Also, I run a single hadoop operation at a time.

**EDIT** 1#:- if this helps, here's the log when I tried running datanode via $HADOOP_HOME.

```
root@thinktank:/usr/local/hadoop/bin# hadoop datanode Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

13/08/27 16:34:57 INFO datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: /********************************** STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode STARTUP_MSG: host = thinktank/127.0.1.1 STARTUP_MSG: args = [] STARTUP_MSG: version = 1.2.1 STARTUP_MSG: build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG: java = 1.6.0_27
**********************************/
13/08/27 16:34:57 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
13/08/27 16:34:57 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
13/08/27 16:34:57 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
13/08/27 16:34:57 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
13/08/27 16:34:57 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
13/08/27 16:34:57 WARN impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
13/08/27 16:34:57 ERROR datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 1955988395; datanode namespaceID = 1705269445 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:232) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:147) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:414) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.(DataNode.java:321) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1712) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1651) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1669) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1795) at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1812)

13/08/27 16:34:57 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: /********************************** SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at thinktank/127.0.1.1 **********************************/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error `Incompatible namespaceIDs`. The cause and solution is well documented on the website you did your tutorial on, so I won't bother describing it here. [Read about it for yourself here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/#javaioioexception-incompatible-namespaceids).

To answer your other question, yes, you can have 2 separate Hadoop installations. Shouldn't cause any problems just don't get them mixed up!

Comment: Delete your datanode persistent directory if there is no data. Some mix up is happening may be because the way you configured and starting your cluster. Make sure your configurations for both versions is proper and started correctly.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I got it up and running. @Rags